# HTTP Error 500 while inserting data to Database

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have the error mentioned in the title. It occurs when I click the submit button on the form. Here is my form handle file (I don't think that its necessary to copy the form codes):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
  $username = "sabashel_sabaadm";
  $password = "saba1365%karaj@*";
$dbname = "sabashel_saba";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$fname = $lname = $gender = $birthdate = $organization = $degree = $field = $address = $post_code = $mobile = $email = $check_1 = $check_2 = $check_3  = $check_4  = $check_5  = $check_6  = $check_7  = $check_8 "";
$check_9 = $check_10  = $check_11  = $check_12  = $check_13 = $description = $person_image = "";



if(isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['birthdate']) && isset($_POST['degree']) && isset($_POST['filed-of-study']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['post-code']) && isset($_POST['mobile']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['check-1']) && isset($_POST['check-2']) && isset($_POST['check-3']) && isset($_POST['check-4']) && isset($_POST['check-5']) && isset($_POST['check-6']) && isset($_POST['check-7']) && isset($_POST['check-8']) && isset($_POST['check-9']) && isset($_POST['check-10']) && isset($_POST['check-11']) && isset($_POST['check-12']) && isset($_POST['check-13']) && isset($_POST['description']) && isset($_POST['person-iamge'])){
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $birthdate = $_POST['birdthdate'];
        $organization = $_POST['organization'];
        $degree = $_POST['degree'];
        $field = $_POST['field-of-study'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $post_code = $_POST['post-code'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $check_1 = $_POST['check-1'];
        $check_2 = $_POST['check-2'];
        $check_3 = $_POST['check-3'];
        $check_4 = $_POST['check-4'];
        $check_5 = $_POST['check-5'];
        $check_6 = $_POST['check-6'];
        $check_7 = $_POST['check-7'];
        $check_8 = $_POST['check-8'];
        $check_9 = $_POST['check-9'];
        $check_10 = $_POST['check-10'];
        $check_11 = $_POST['check-11'];
        $check_12 = $_POST['check-12'];
        $check_13 = $_POST['check-13'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $person_image = $_POST['person-image'];
        $iftest = true;
  }
  if ($iftest == true) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO volunteer (fname, lname, gender, organization, degree, field, address, post_code, mobile, email, check_1, check_2, check_3, check_4, check_5, check_6, check_7, check_8, check_9, check_10, check_11, check_12, check_13, description, person_image, birthdate) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$gender', '$organization', '$degree', '$field', '$address', '$post_code', '$mobile', '$email', '$check_1', '$check_2', '$check_3', '$check_4', '$check_5', '$check_6', '$check_7', '$check_8', '$check_9', '$check_10', '$check_11', '$check_12', '$check_13', '$description', '$person_image', '$birthdate')";
  }


  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  if ($result) {
      header('Location: http://sabashelter.com/success');
    }
    else {
      header('Location: http://sabashelter.com/fail');
    }
}


$conn->close();
?>
```

And to mention: I have the same exact problem with another page which does the same thing and tries to add a lot of values into the database using the same code. I'm wondering if the problem in this page solves, the same method can be done to the other page as well.

Comment: -1 for coming here with a 500 error, without telling us what the error log has to say about it. You _always_ do that first on this type of error.

Comment: `= $check_8 "";` issue there.

Comment: Also look into using arrays, instead of many variables, and and and dont forget to change the code to use prepared queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe rightly says, check your log files **first**. It would appear that you are missing an `=` on line 14.

```
$fname = $lname = $gender = $birthdate = $organization = $degree = $field = $address = $post_code = $mobile = $email = $check_1 = $check_2 = $check_3  = $check_4  = $check_5  = $check_6  = $check_7  = $check_8 = "";
```

Furthermore, you have a stray `}` on line 60.

Your error log file will help you resolve these issues.

Comment: Yes, the thing is I'm fairly new to web programming so I really don't know how to maintain my problems. So if you can be kind to actually tell me how to do that, it would be superly great.